# C# Delegate vs Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I'm trying to optimize a method and can't get to the solution..

I have the following class:

```
public class X : MyInterface<Model>
{
    public void Execute(Model m) { }
}
```

I am trying to invoke Execute(...)
I know the Type of X and I know the Type of Model.

This works:

```
(here logic to find the correct method).Method.Invoke(InstanceX, new object[] { m });
```

This does not but should work faster:

```
(here logic to find the correct method).Method.CreateDelegate(Expression.GetDelegateType(typeof(m)), instanceX);
```

Error:
Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Again; trying to optimize, so any other solution that works faster than the reflection Invoke would be cool.

Comment: Why do you need to invoke Execute(...) via reflection ?

Comment: I have: - Model instance - typeof(X) - typeof(Model) =>
The code I write creates an instance of X, and calls Execute with the instance of Model as parameter.

Comment: You need to add typeof(void) to get an Action instead of a Func delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution without reflection (to create delegate):

```
// assuming existence of class BaseModel and class XModel : BaseModel

public interface IBaseClass {
  void Execute(BaseModel model);
}

public abstract class BaseClass<TModel> : IBaseClass where TModel : BaseModel {
  public void Execute(BaseModel model) {
    this.Execute((TModel)model);
  }
  protected abstract void Execute(TModel model);
}

public class X : BaseClass<XModel> {
  protected override Execute(XModel model) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var typeX = typeof(X);
var typeXModel = typeof(XModel);
var x = (IBaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeX);
x.Execute((BaseModel)Activator.CreateInstance(typeXModel));
```